# не подписывается приложение android

Tags: android, android-studio

создал сертификат. gradle не ругается. А вот телефону что то не нравится[image]

до этого уже подписывал приложение сертификатом, а после некоторых изменений в коде телефон стал ругаться

Comment: Опишите как подписываете, в Gradle или вручную?

Comment: в gradle. потом выбираю пункт "generate signet apk"

Comment: Не понял. Как мне известно есть 2 способа подписи: 1. Из меню -> Build -> Generate signed APK. 2. В gradle [пруф](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328730/how-to-create-a-release-signed-apk-file-using-gradle).

Comment: А что делаете после подписи? Откуда APK берете? Если подписали apk ручками, тогда если запустите Shift+F10 apk будет другой, не подписанный.

Comment: А почему написано App Store?

Comment: Я почему то использовал оба метода. И не один не роботал. У этого проэкта было две разные подписи сначала одна потом другая. Я думаю из за этого приложение не подписывается. Брал я приложение из папки. А appstore написано потому что это телефон Meizu. Он всегда так реагирует на неподписанные приложения. Решением проблемы для меня стало создание нового проэкта. Теперь я для подписываня использую первый способ  build-->generate signet apk